# Tcl flush command returns error

Tags: tcl

I've gotten this error from Tcl `flush` command:

```
error flushing "stdout": I/O error
```

Any ideas why it can happen? Also, the man page doesn't say anything about `flush` returning errors. Can the same error come from `puts`?
And ultimately: what do do about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Tcl uses line buffering on `stdout` (more on this later).  This means whatever you `puts` there gets buffered and is only output when the newline is seen in the buffer or when you `flush` the channel.  So, yes, you can get the same error from `puts` directly, if a call to it is done on an unbuffered channel or if it managed to hit that "buffer full" condition so that the underlying medium is really accessed.

As to "I/O error", we do really need more details.  Supposedly the `stdout` of your program has been redirected (or [reopened](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3995)), and the underlying media is inaccessible for some reason.

You could try to infer more details about the cause by inspecting the [`POSIX` `errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) of the actual failing syscall — it's accessible via the global [`errorCode` variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/return.htm#M13) after a Tcl command involving such a syscall signalized error condition.  So you could go like this:

```
set rc [catch {flush stdout} err]
if {$rc != 0} {
    global errorCode
    set fd [open error.log w]
    puts $fd $err\n\n$errorCode
    close $fd
}
```

(since Tcl 8.5 you can directly ask `catch` to return all the relevant info instead of inspecting magic variables, see the manual).

Providing more details on how you run your program or whether you reopen `stdout` is strongly suggested.

---

A note on buffering.  Output buffering can be controlled using `fconfigure` (or `chan configure` since 8.5 onwards) on a channel by manipulating its `-buffering` option.  Usually it's set to `line` on `stdout` but it can be set to `full` or `none`.  When set to `full`, the `-buffersize` option can be used to control the buffer size explicitly.

Comment: The POSIX error code won't say much; that message means there was an `EIO` error coming out of the `write()` syscall and that's not a very informative one.